# How can I make one bash subshell exit the main calling shell script?

Tags: bash, exit, exit-code, subshell

Having the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function foo() {
  # commands that might fails and I want to exit my script
  ...
  echo "result I need as output"
}

my_var=$(foo)

echo "I don't want this if there is an error inside foo"
```

Using `set -e` (in bash `4.4.19`) does not seem to work with subshells i.e. the last `echo` command is still being executed). How can I write the code to make the script exit if any of the commands inside `foo` terminate with non-zero exit code.

I am using bash `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0)` and the result of calling my script is (where the dots are replaced with an invalid command `head -this`:

```
$ ./my_script
head: illegal option -- t
usage: head [-n lines | -c bytes] [file ...]
I don't want this if there is an error inside foo
```

Comment: because you didn't check the exit status of `head`; either `head .. || exit 1`, either enabling `-e` option inside subshell `my_var=$(set -e; foo)`, the first is better because explicit and easier for other to understand

Comment: And if `head` is actually `grep ... | head ... | awk ... | xargs ...` command, how can you rewrite these pipes? Using  `(grep ... || exit 1) | (head ... || exit 1) | ...`?

Comment: for a pipeline command by default exit status is the exit status of the last command of the pipeline, but can also be changed by `set -o pipefail`, note that `pipefail` is not cleared in subshell

Comment: Thanks! If you add this options to the answer with a corresponding comment, I think it would be useful as well. This is what I actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changed from comments

the exit status of a pipeline command is the exit status of the last command, this can be changed using `set -o pipefail`, so that pipeline exit status will be `<>0` is any command exit status is `<>0`.

### First answer

as you used the `-e` option it is sufficient that the function returns a non `0` exit code for example `return 1`

in a more general case (without `set -e`), it can be better to use an explicit exit

```
my_var=$(foo) || exit 1
```

can be sufficient because error could be written on standard error (inherited) by subshell.

otherwise reading carefully manual can explain why it doesn't work as you expected

> set
> -e
>
> Exit immediately if [...] returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, [...].
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> [...]

And from Command Execution Environment

> Subshells spawned to execute command substitutions inherit the value of the -e option from the parent shell. When not in POSIX mode, Bash clears the -e option in such subshells.